# Long exact sequence from a short exact sequence of double complexes

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra

I'm having trouble finding a reference for something that I think should be in the literature.  Consider a short exact sequence of bounded double-complexes, in an abelian category:
$$0 \rightarrow A^{\bullet, \bullet} \rightarrow B^{\bullet, \bullet} \rightarrow C^{\bullet, \bullet} \rightarrow 0.$$

Let $H^n(A) = H^n(Tot \  A^{\bullet, \bullet})$ be the cohomology of the total complex of $A^{\bullet, \bullet}$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$.  I think that one obtains a long exact sequence in cohomology,
$$0 \rightarrow H^0(A) \rightarrow H^0(B) \rightarrow H^0(C) \rightarrow H^1(A) \rightarrow \cdots.$$

On the other hand, the double complexes induce two filtrations on these cohomology group.   Choose one of these filtrations, giving $F^p H^n(A)$ and $F^p H^n(B)$ and $F^p H^n(C)$.

In what way is the long exact sequence above compatible with the filtrations?  I can probably work this out with some triple-complex argument, but it must be "well-known" to somebody (Hodge theorists?).  Is this written down in generality somewhere?

Comment: From the s.e.s. of double-complexes, you get a s.e.s. of total complexes by adding up. This gives you the l.e.s. in cohomology you wrote down. Since the s.e.s. of total complexes consists respects the filtrations, the same will be true for the l.e.s.

Comment: It's not so obvious to me what this means, and kind of shifts the question over to filtered-complex land.  I.e., given a s.e.s. of filtered complexes, in what way does the l.e.s. respect the filtrations?  Reference?

Comment: Concerning your last question, isn't this obvious from the definition of the maps in the l.e.s.? (2 x induced maps, 1 x snake lemma)